# In which cases using of laravel passport gives some advantage?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I read https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport now and it is clear technically, but in which cases have I to use it to get
advantage comparing with laravel native auth or jwt/auth I worked before?

1) In config/auth.php 'guards' we set which auth driver would be used in the app
and it can be only 1 set. I mean we can not set passport and jwt/auth in 1 app?

2) Looks like passport can be used in case when we use blade page and form is submitted as we do in blade page as :

```
   <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
       @csrf
```

I suppose there is no difference in blade forms definition using passport intead of native auth?

3) Also, passport can be used instead of jwt/auth in backend rest API and there is no difference in work of clients app
 using this backend rest API ?

4) Is passport better/has some advantage in both cases or it is just one more replacement?

5) Please give some examples in which passport can be used / got advantage of using it may be in some other app types?

Thanks!

Comment: It has some uses if you setup up an SSO server.

Comment: Passport is an oauth2 provider. If you don't know why that would be an advantage in your application then it probably isn't

Comment: Thanks for you feedbacks!
I have not worked with SSO servers before.
I mean if I make some applications with several blocks it has one auth system.
Looks like SSO server means several apps by different providers/developers, which can not have 1 auth system?
Can you please give some examples from your appearance, preferrably when some parts were created by you(your team)
and other by side developers?

Are points 1) 2) 3) correct in my topic?
Please answer point 4)

Comment: @ Nicklas Kevin Frank, Thanks! I worked  with laravel/socialite to login to my app with Facebook, Twitter ...
 accounts, though my app has native auth, not passport. I suppose Facebook, Twitter ... has oauth2 implemented with passport
 (or similar library) to give access to my app with its account?

Comment: @PetroGromovo Yes - Facebook, Twitter, etc. could have used a Library like Passport to make you and other people able to login using something like Socialite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel Passport is a Laravel package that allows you to integrate the OAUTH2 protocol into your application.

This means that when you want other services to retrieve user data from your application, or add data, they can request access for users. Users can give permissions for certain actions by clicking a button on the external site, logging in on their account on your Laravel site, and allowing access for the external service. Users are then redirected back to the other website, and after a few requests between the two servers, the external service now has the requested permissions to read or alter user data. This protocol is almost always used whenever you click "sign on with ..." since all large social media platforms have OAUTH2 integrations.

To answer your questions:

1. I believe this question: [Laravel combine Passport authentication and normal authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55110580/laravel-combine-passport-authentication-and-normal-authentication) will answer your question.
2. Passport sits on top of default Laravel auth and needs this to authenticate requests. So users still have to have an account on your site to allow other websites to access your account.
3. There are big differences in how normal API auth works, and how Passport works. The biggest difference is that normal API auth should only be used for your site, not for external sites to fetch user data from your API. With OAUTH2, users can give certain permissions to websites, and using tokens, these external sites can perform certain actions on your site.
4. If you want to allow other sites to fetch account information from your site, you should implement Passport, if not, then using Passport has no large advantages.
5. Examples are things like `Sign in with Google`, or with Facebook, Twitter or GitHub, Even stackoverflow has an OAUTH2 implementation. Services can, for example, create new Facebook posts for a user, request all twitter posts from the last year or create a new issue in Github.

Comment: Technically speaking passport is not an SSO provider, it's an OAuth2 provider which *could* be used to develop SSO **among other things**. SSO is a much more restricted concept while OAuth2 can e.g. be used to power an API for example where sign-on will not actually be happening but requests will be authorized instead.

Comment: @Tim, Thanks!
As for point 5)
about 10 years ago in symphony 1 app I had a task from my app with logged account to login into phpBB
I found in net some decision how to make it, not oauth2.
I am not sure oauth2 was invented at this time.

Looks like oauth2 is just fior this purpoce, with this https://phpbbstudio.com/viewforum.php?f=39as 
branch ?